# How to make more columns from one?

Tags: excel-2007

I exported in excel many rows with all kind of information, but all I need is what I have after the `CN=` . Is it a way to extract just the name or to put in separate columns the information between the commas?

```
"CN=John Binn,OU=Users02,OU=Users,OU=siu1,OU=robot,DC=robots,DC=com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text to columns button under the data tab has what you are looking for. Highlight your data, click text to columns, set the data type to delimited, then set the delimiter to a comma and you are rolling.

One warning though, you need to have enough empty cells to the right of your highlighted column, or you will delete what was in those cells previously. Just insert some blank columns if this is the case.